# Prove $\frac{\sin(a)}{\sin(b)}<\frac{a}{b}<\frac{\tan(a)}{\tan(b)}$ for $0<b<a<\pi/2$

Tags: inequality

not sure how to approach the following $\frac{\sin(a)}{\sin(b)}<\frac{a}{b}<\frac{\tan(a)}{\tan(b)}$ for $0<b<a<\pi/2$. Hints would be appreciated!

Comment: for the last one you just have to prove that $\frac{\cos(b)}{\cos(a)}>1$ to get that it is larger than the ratio of sines. This is obvious from the fact that it is monotonically decreasing on that interval.

Comment: Are you allowed to differentiate?

Comment: This is [Aristarchus' inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristarchus'_inequality).  It was used by [Ptolemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy) in constructing his [table of chords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the function $\frac{\sin x}x$ is decreasing:
$$\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)'=\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}=\frac{\cos x}{x^2}(x-\tan x)<0,$$
because $\cos x>0$ and $\tan x>x$ on $(0,\frac\pi2)$.

So for $\frac\pi2>a>b>0$ we have $\frac{\sin a}a<\frac{\sin b}b\Longrightarrow\frac{\sin a}{\sin b}<\frac ab$.

Additionally $\frac{\tan x}x$ is increasing:
$$\left(\frac{\tan x}x\right)'=\frac{\frac{x}{\cos^2 x}-\tan x}{x^2}=\frac{x-\sin x\cos x}{x^2\cos^2 x}=\frac{2x-\sin(2x)}{2x^2\cos^2x}>0,$$
because $\sin x<x$ on $(0,\infty)$.

So for $\frac\pi2>a>b>0$ we have $\frac{\tan a}a>\frac{\tan b}b\Longrightarrow\frac ab<\frac{\tan a}{\tan b}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
separation of $(a,b)$.

details:

1. for the first one, consider
   $$g(x) = \frac x{\sin x}
   \\
   g'(x) = \frac 1{\sin x} - \frac {x\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=
   \frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x} (\tan x - x)> 0
   $$
   so $g$ is strictly increasing, and $$
   \frac b{\sin b}< \frac a{\sin a}\iff \frac{\sin a}{\sin b} <\frac ab
   $$
2. For the second one, do the same thing with
   $$
   h(x) = \frac{\tan x}x
   $$