# Prove inequality between functions

Tags: inequality

Show that $x^2<\tan{x}\arctan{x}$ if $x\in(0;\pi/2)$. I have thought about proving that $f(x) = \tan{x}\arctan{x} - x^2$ is monotonically increasing(its derivative is larger than 0), but its derivative ($f'(x) = \frac{\arctan{x}}{\cos^2x} + \frac{\tan x}{1 + x^2}-2x$) is hard to compare with 0. Please, can you give me a hint?

Comment: I have no idea what you need to do but did you try for example a variable change like $x=\tan(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\tan x > x$ for all $x \in \left( 0,\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)$, $\dfrac{\tan(x)}{x}> 1$.  We claim that [$g(x) = \dfrac{\tan(x)}{x}$ is strictly increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/724035/290189) on that interval.

> $$g'(x) = \left(\frac{\tan x}x\right)'=\frac{\frac{x}{\cos^2 x}-\tan x}{x^2}=\frac{x-\sin x\cos x}{x^2\cos^2 x}=\frac{2x-\sin(2x)}{2x^2\cos^2x}>0,$$  Source: linked answer

Consider $g(\arctan x) < g(x)$, and you'll get the desired inequality.

> $$\frac{x}{\arctan x}<\frac{\tan x}{x} \iff \tan x \arctan x > x^2$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Put it this way: you have to prove that

$$\frac{x}{\arctan x}<\frac{\tan x}{x}$$

Introduce:

$$x=\tan y$$

...and notice that $x>y$.

With this in mind you have to prove that:

$$\frac{\tan y}{y}<\frac{\tan x}{x}$$

In other words, you have to prove that $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ is strictly increasing. The first derivative is:

$$(\frac{\tan x}{x})'=\frac{2x-\sin 2x}{2x^2}$$

You should be able to draw the right conclusion from here.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! I think I can easily prove that $\frac{\tan }{x}$ is strictly increasing

Comment: @ErlGrey It's polite to upvote the answers that you liked. Otherwise people won't jump in the next time you need their help.